# How do I get my button to redirect to a different website when pressed?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have been trying to get my button to redirect to this website when clicked, the first button works but whenever I press the second button it tells me the browser sent a request that it could not understand

````
@app.route('/fetch/contract')
def contract_page():
    return redirect("https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x01be23585060835e02b77ef475b0cc51aa1e0709?a=0xffcd77dfe5a79a63927f239ec15f464069c984c1")


@app.route('/fetch', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fetch_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['fetch'] == 'Fetch':
            data = "https://7lsz2q3ku0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/items"
            return display_data(data)
        elif request.form['address'] == 'Contract':
            return redirect(url_for('contract_page'))

    else:
        return render_template("fetch.html")```
````

Answer (score 0):

The request that you are making is of POST. Ideally it should be GET. Making GET request to the URL will give you output as below which I can see right:

```
{
"Item": {
    "id": 1,
    "temp": 75.56,
    "humidity": 55.8
}
```

}

Or You need to handle the use case for GET method too. In else part you are just rendering the template. Something like below:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
  Do Stuffs....
```